# How to show power point presentations on web, without using Inerop or PowerPoint installation on server?

Tags: asp.net

Need to show power point presentations on web with its animations. Is there any converter to convert Presentations to Silverlight/flash/Html without using any Interop or PowerPoint installation on web server?

Answer (score 0):

Google docs has PowerPoint support. You can create and upload .ppt files and display them in a browser, I'm not sure if all the functionality would be there but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

there is many solution but you have to choose best among
Currently i am developing such kind of application but i choose xps viewer, first i convert ppt file to xps and after that i use xps viewer to show it. but xps viewer does not support all ms power point features, visit

http://www.devcurry.com/2009/09/convert-ppt-to-silverlight.html
  [Online PPT Viewer with all power point support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401460/online-ppt-viewer-with-all-power-point-support)