# Online PPT Viewer with all power point support

Tags: asp.net

I am looking to develop online ppt viewer which supports all the feature of MS Power Point, I searched all the sites but did not find any good work. So I tried to convert ppt to xps and then show that xps in xps viewer, but xps viewer does not support all the feature of ms power point. 
can you guide me how to show ppt file online with all MS Power Point features?

Comment: thanks for do you know how can i do this in asp.net or what technology you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1: (Requires lots of work)**
1. Export PPT to XPS
2. Write a custom display (UserControl) which will display your XPS. (Refer to http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Dissecting-XPS-part-1--The-basics.aspx and the entire 8 Part series)
3. Enhance your User Control (Developed in Step #2) to allow editing by maipulating the XPS' XML

**Solution 2:** 
Integrate your PPT with SharePoint Office Web Apps 2010.
1. Open your PPT in an iFrame (using SharePoint's Url). Office Web Apps 2010 allows you to edit PowerPoint slides in a browser.